# Json.net deserialize json with circular reference in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, json.net

I am trying with no luck to deserialize object graph with circular reference,

Json.net works well when serializing circular references : adding a $id to objects and replacing objects with $ref = *objectId,
When i send the same data back to the MVC action, it won't deserialize correctly - replacing the $refs with empty objects.

I use json.net to both serialize and deserialize, deserializing is implemented in a custom IValueProvider - https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/347099

I noticed that when deserializing to an anonymous object

```
JsonConverter.Deserialize(json);
```

it will not deal with the circular references.
but when deserializing using a generic type

```
JsonConverter.Deserialize<EntityType>(json)
```

it will deserialize correctly.

But i can't find the type in the GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)

any help will be appreciated

Edit-
In my current fix i pass the whole json as a string and use

```
JsonConverter.Deserialize<EntityType>(json)
```

with the right type in the controller's action, but that's definitely not the right way to work with json + mvc4...
I need a better way to integrate it into mvc, started a bounty

Edit- More code
The type :

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class DynamicEntity : EntityWithID<Guid>
{
    ....

    public virtual IList<DynamicEntity> ReferenceFields { get; set; }
}
```

The json to deserialize is the output of the Serialize method of Json.net.

```
{"$id":"1","ReferenceFields":[{"$ref":"1"}],"Id":"9f9de7f3-865e-4511-aeac-a2ff01193b06"}
```

The issue is the integration with MVC because the json goes back and forth between the server and client.
I already have js methods to change it back and forth to the same exact format - tested as i use it like this for now :

```
public ActionResult EntitySaveOrUpdate(string entity)
    {
        var entityToSave = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DynamicEntity>(entity);
        ...
    }
```

And it works just fine, but i need a better integration with MVC and not deserialize in all of my actions...

Comment: As far as I've been taught circular references are bad and will give unexpected behavior, but perhaps i don't understand the question. Have to stepped into the code when sending the data back to mvc to see what it is before deserialization

Comment: The data is fine, in the custom ValueProvider in MVC (link in the question) there's a Deserialize, Json.Net's Deserialize works well only when you pass it the actual type - which i cannot find in the controllerContext.

as to circular references - with inverse relationships you can't avoid them.

Comment: Can you output some of the JSON so we can see the format of it and the circular record. Can you also show the code for an `EntityType` it would deserialize to?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is your issue the circular reference (which doesn't seem to be the case), or that you want to de-serialize to anonymous rather than defined type (which seems to be real question)?

Comment: My issue is the integration of the circular reference behaviour of Json.Net (needing the typed deserialize) with MVC's ValueProvider/ModelBinder pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
The challenge is dynamically typing at compile-time an un-typed languages (JSON).
```

Since ***JSON*** is actually ***Java-Script Object Notation***, and ***JavaScript*** is weakly typed (or un-typed), the compile-time interpreter isn't sure if "1" refers to an ***int***, ***double***, or ***string*** type.

Notice, you don't get the same problem when you use a ***DynamicEntity***, because the Run-Time is allowed to interpret in similar manner to ***JavaScript***.

- [This post](http://blogs.aedigital.com/post/2010/08/22/Deserializing-JSON-to-anonymous-types-in-C) of how dynamics and static-anonymous-types treat deserialization is a little old, but still relevant. Their approach is to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()` -- a dynamic method -- to return anonymous.
- [This post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/09/Using-an-alternate-JSON-Serializer-in-ASPNET-Web-API) expands on ***Web Api***'s `DataContractJsonSerializer`, and how it limits your options with anonymous types. The answer suggested is to

> "to replace the MediaTypeFormatter and plug in our own JSON serializer"

This amounts to a lot of work for your limited needs.

What you'll find is, short of using ***Linq*** projection, your ***DynamicEntity*** is probably as good approach as you will find.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to write JsonConverter and register it in your ValueProviderFactory.

```
JSONSerializer.Converters.Add(new DynamicEntityObjectConverter());
```

And inside your converter you can manualy use `JsonConverter.Deserialize<EntityType>(json)` which works for circular reference.